# MaterialApp's theme colors not respected in second route

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and am trying to create a 2 pages (or `routes`) app.
I have one basic page with some kind of a form, while the other has a `GridView`.

I'm using a `MaterialApp` as per in the demo app, and a theme. On the root page (the form), text color is as expected **black**. However, every tiles of my grid on the second page contain their own text, colored **red** and **underlined yellow**.

Could you give me a hint as to why ?

(Btw, I compute the ratio of my gridview's cells using the context dimensions. I am not satisfied with this solution since if I were to had padding to my `Container`, the grid would overflow in height. Is there a better way ? Consider this as a side quest-ion =))

Here is the portion of the code.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Create a game'),
        '/game': (context) => const Game(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And for the second page:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Game extends StatelessWidget {
  const Game({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Grid();
  }
}

class Grid extends StatefulWidget {
  var tokens = List<int>.filled(9, 0);

  Grid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GridState createState() => _GridState();
}

class _GridState extends State<Grid> {
  final _gridViewCrossAxisCount = 3;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: _gridViewCrossAxisCount,
                childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
              itemCount: widget.tokens.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: cellDecoration(index, _gridViewCrossAxisCount),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(widget.tokens[index].toString()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

BoxDecoration cellDecoration(int index, int gridViewCrossAxisCount) {
  return BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black12,
      width: 1.5,
    ),
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a scaffold in second screen. Wrap the expanded widget with a scaffold and the text will render as per the text theme mentioned in material app

Comment: I thought theme was MaterialApp dependent, whatever the child widgets